# iOS / Uber integration: link_text and partner_deeplink not working in testing

Tags: ios, uber-api

I'm making an iOS (v8.3+) app which is a mapping app. The user can define a starting point and destination. They can then tap the Share button and choose "Open in Uber", which will launch the Uber app via a deeplink URL like this:

uber://?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&action=setPickup&link_text=Watch%20progress%20in%20my%20app&partner_deeplink=SOMEDEEPLINK%3A%2F%2F&pickup[latitude]=123.456&pickup[longitude]=123.456&pickup[nickname]=PICKUP&pickup[formatted_address]=123%20Elm%20St&dropoff[latitude]=123.456&dropoff[longitude]=123.456&dropoff[nickname]=DROPOFF&dropoff[formatted_address]=456%20Elm%20St

(This sample URL includes some obviously fake data, for the sake of simplicity.)

I've registered at Uber and have a valid client ID. This call (via openURL) works correctly: the Uber app launches with the starting point and destination already populated. This is ALL that I've done with Uber; there's no other calls being made at all.

The problem is that the special branding text does not appear within the Uber app during the trip (and of course the related partner_deeplink doesn't work either).

What do I need to do in order to get it to work? Do I need to "enable" this functionality somehow? My app has registered its own custom URL scheme that I use as the "partner_deeplink=SOMEDEEPLINK%3A%2F%2F" portion of the uber:// URL. I know this works because I can use my custom URL scheme in Safari and it successfully launches my app.

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `Request Full Access` in the [Uber Developer Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard) to get activated for the Trip Branding feature. Please check out the documentation [here](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/deep-linking-trip-branding).

As soon as you're activated, you can set defaults for the custom assets and the deeplink parameters you're referring to are essentially used to dynamically override these defaults.

Comment: OK thanks. I filled out that form in order to ask this question, which I then posted to stackoverflow (above). The dashboard says my application is still pending. But even with my question as the submission, you haven't actually seen my app yet. I can send a TestFlight invitation to someone there if you need it. Basically, I'm assuming that someone will contact me if they need more info?

Comment: Got it! Yes, your assumption is correct. If more information will be needed, you will be approached. Please allow some time to validate your request. Thanks!

Comment: It's been 3 weeks and I still haven't heard anything from Uber.

Comment: Did you check your spam folder? Could you follow up with @UberDevelopers on Twitter per DM with your client_id, please? That way, we can double check and resolve this asap. Sorry for the delay in your request!

Comment: Nothing in spam folder. My dashboard still reads "full access pending." I don't really use Twitter -- can you folks reply to me another way? I feel like I'm doing support here on SO and it just feels Wrong ;-)

Comment: What's your email? We can't expose details like client ID in SO, so let's switch to a more private channel.

Comment: I just found your personal web site and sent it to you there. :) It didn't seem like posting my email was a commonly-done thing here. Thanks!

Comment: Agree, let's continue conversations over emails. Thanks!